# Listing out maximum price by titles with title name?

Tags: sql, group-by, clause

I have a database for exercises. I would like to list out the maximum price of different types with the corresponding title name, but of course I can't just put the title name attribute into my SELECT clause, because it does not appear in the GROUP BY clause. Is there any solution to my problem? Thanks!

```
SELECT type, MAX(price) "price"
FROM titles
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the database you are using.  Most databases support the ANSI standard `row_number()` and window/analytic functions.  Here is one method to do what you want:

```
select type, name, price
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by price desc) as seqnum
      from titles t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In the case of MySQL, which does not support `row_number()`, you can do:

```
select type,
       substring_index(group_concat(name separator '|' order by price desc), '|', 1) as title,
       max(price) as price
from titles
group by type;
```

Note that this assumes that no title contains the character `'|'`.